# Return index and object from list on a single query?

Tags: c#, linq, list, sql-order-by

I have List where MyClass is composed of 3 fields, int id, double price and string name, I would like now to order it by desc score and retrive a given object and its position, **how could I archieve this ?**

First thing that came to my mind was:

```
var find = score.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
```

Which does get me the item but I still need it is position.

**Is there a way to return found with both, the object and the position it is on the list ?**

I could do a foreach each on the result but I wonder if there are a better way with LINQ or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project to an anonymous class and use the `Select()` overload that gets you the index:

```
var find = score.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
                .Select( (x,i) => new { Item = x, Position = i })
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.ID == id);
```

Comment: Cool that works, nice to see that implementation, is the cost of it big or not noticeable ?

Comment: @Prix: There should be no perceptible performance difference, although you do add a little overhead of course

Comment: I was expecting some little overhead, was just wondering because it does look pretty straight forward ;) wasn't aware I could actually do something like that until now.